# Single SQL server database table used by many users simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does it effect the performance of my web Application if many users use single table of SQL Server database simultaneously...?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very general, it depends upon number of concurrent users per second and design of application code keeping an eye on atomicity.

Comment: Bilal Ayub at least how much concurrent users would effect the performance ...?

Comment: It's a long discussion where your server (web and DB) play an important role. More the number of core more number of thread handling capabilities.